# steps to write a react component that should support javascript and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

I’d like to build a react component that should support both javascript and typescript also want to publish it to the npm repository as a package

To achieve this what are the best practices that I should follow?

Is it required to write the code in both TS and JS or do we have any tools that convert TS to JS?

Comment: Generally, you'll write pure typescript and compile it to js + d.ts files using a tool like tsc or babel before publishing

Comment: Thanks, DustlnComp, 
if you can share any reference with me, that would be a great help.

Comment: You'll find plenty of walkthroughs if you just google "how to build a ts react library", like this one https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-component-library-react-typescript/